# Not getting correct date from DateTime in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I need only date in the  **yyyy-MM-dd** format, but I'm getting (20/03/2018 0:00:00) date in wrong format.

```
var d = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-03-20T00:00:00.000",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
var finaldate = DateTime.TryParseExact(d, "yyyy-MM-dd", null);
```

Output i am getting --20/03/2018 0:00:00
expected -- **2018-03-20**

Comment: When adding tags to your question, look at the tags you select! Make sure they are correct.

Comment: You are confusing types with how these are displayed somewhere, for example in the debugger. `DateTime` has no format

Comment: You're picking a string, converting a date, then to a string of a different format only to parse it back to a date. I don't get what you want to do after all this.

Comment: If you print `d` , you will get the exact output you are looking for

Comment: "DateTime has no format" should be a selectable close reason ...

Answer (score 4):

I will try to explain what the others meant when they wrote "DateTime has no format".

`DateTime` is a C# type that has properties for year, month, day, etc.

If you want to print a `DateTime`, you first have to convert it to a `string`. During this conversion, you can define the output format.

Also, if you parse a `string` into a `DateTime`, you can define the expected input format.

This is what the "[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)" / "[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)" are for.

An example:

```
string d = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-03-20T00:00:00.000",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTime finaldate = DateTime.TryParseExact(d, "yyyy-MM-dd", null); // not a string!

int year = finadate.Year;    // year == 2018 (a number!)
int month = finaldate.Month; // month == 3 (a number again!)

string isoFormat = finaldate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); // isoFormat == "2018-03-20"
string usFormat = finaldate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");  // usFormat == "03/20/2018"
// and so on...
```

Note that if you just call `ToString()` without specifying any format, the result will depend on the culture of the current thread (probably "en-Us" judging from the output you have shown). See [DateTime.ToString Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Could you please also add link to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings so I will remove my answer

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` always returns `DateTime` object with the time part. 
To get expected output, you have to return string eg. `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`